# custom web component form element for constraint validation

Tags: html, web-component, native-web-component, constraint-validation-api

Only some HTMLElements support the constraint validation api (e.g., HTMLButtonElement). I want to create a custom web component, which also supports the constraint validation api.

In the following an example is given for the desired outcome:

```html
<form>
  <input name="title" required>
  <custom-form-component></custom-form-component>
</form>
<script>
  const form = document.querySelector('form');
  form.checkValidity();
</script>
```

The `custom-form-component` could call `setCustomValidity` on itself (based on the respective user input context) and validate itself true or false. Thus, the call on the `form.checkValidity()` should return true or false with respect to the outcome of the `custom-form-component`.

As I found from documentaion (e.g. on MDN) only for some element it is possible to attach a shadow root. It is not possible for form elements. However, only form elements suport the constraint validation api.

concrete question:
How can I realise a custom web component, which supports constraint validation api?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a new introduction to Web Components. As of Sept 25, 2019 only Chrome 76 supports it.

Here is an article provided by Google Web Devs:

https://web.dev/more-capable-form-controls/

It talks about the various additions to Web Components that let them properly integrate as a form element.

This includes:

1. Form validation
2. The `:disabled`, `:invalid` and `:valid` CSS pseudoclasses
3. The `formdata` event
4. And a static `formAssociated` property that tells the browser to treat your element like a form control.

Plus several other things that allows your control to function correction in a `<form>`